# Python Get value in json

Tags: python, json

I need get values from key "color" in json using python, only for first level

json dumps:

```
[{"color": "red", "value": "10"}, {"color": "blue", "value": [{"color": "black", "value": "15"}]}]
```

I need:

```
[ 'red', 'blue']
```

I tried:

```
my_values = my_json_a.get('color')
```

But with error:

```
Error Contents: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: This `[i['color'] for i in my_json ]`?

Comment: @JasonEstibeiro `[dic.get("color") for dic in my_json]` would be preferable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
data = [{"color": "red", "value": "10"}, {"color": "blue", "value": [{"color": "black", "value": "15"}]}]
results = [x.get('color', None) for x in data]
print results
```

Output:

```
['red', 'blue']
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a for loop to loop through your json string and append each color value to a new list.

```
json = [{"color": "red", "value": "10"}, {"color": "blue", "value": [{"color": "black", "value": "15"}]}]
colors =[]
for i in json:
    colors.append(i["color"])
print(colors)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because

```
[{"color": "red", "value": "10"}, {"color": "blue", "value": [{"color": "black", "value": "15"}]}]
```

is a list, let's test:

```
>>> my_json_a = [{"color": "red", "value": "10"}, {"color": "blue", "value": [{"color": "black", "value": "15"}]}]

>>> type(my_json_a)
<class 'list'>

>>> for i in my_json_a:
...     print(i)
...     print(type(i))

{'value': '10', 'color': 'red'}
<class 'dict'>
{'value': [{'value': '15', 'color': 'black'}], 'color': 'blue'}
<class 'dict'>
```

So it's a list and there's 2 dicts in it, so you need extract them. You can simply use a list comprehension to do it like this:

```
>>> my_values = [i.get('color') for i in my_json_a]
>>> my_values
['red', 'blue']
>>>
```